# $f(yf^2(x))=x^3f(xy)$ for all $x,y \in {\mathbb{Q}}^{+}$

Tags: number-theory, functions, functional-equations, education

Find all functions $f: {\mathbb{Q}}^{+} \rightarrow {\mathbb{Q}}^{+}$ such that: 
$f(yf^2(x))=x^3f(xy)$ for all $x,y \in {\mathbb{Q}}^{+}$ 
My progress: 
$P(x;1) \Rightarrow f(f^2(x))=x^3f(x)$ 
Easily we have $f$ is injective. 
$P(1;y) \Rightarrow f(yf^2(1))=f(y) \Rightarrow f(1)=1$ 
$P \left(x;\dfrac{1}{x} \right) \Rightarrow f \left(\dfrac{f^2(x)}{x} \right)=x^3$ 
$\Rightarrow f \left(\dfrac{f^2(x)}{x} \right) \cdot f(x)=f(f^2(x))$ 
I wondered if f is multiplicative.

Comment: Oh thank you very much

Comment: When I edit I did't see that problem

Comment: I found it using [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/). Please try searching for similar problems before posting duplicates.